# How to start a service after X server starts in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I have created one application which runs as a service. For that, I have written one script and placed it into /etc/init.d

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    su -c "cd /opt/myservice; ./Watchdog.sh &"
    ;;
  stop)
    killall -15 Watchdog.sh
    killall -15 myApp
    ;;
esac
```

My application opens some live video streams. Above script starts my application when I install it and I can able to watch live streams.

But when I restart my machine, that time my service gets start but live streams doesn't get start. I have searched the web for this issue. In some links, I read that we need to start services like this after X server starts. But I don't know how to do this.